# Change opacity of another form

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

I'm making a program, and i have another form inside the program with options for the program. The options are `Checkboxes` that are supposed to enable opacity. Can i change the opacity of the main form with the other form?

```
private void useOpacity_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (useOpacity.Checked)
    {
         window().Opacity = .75;
    }
}
```

something like this...

Answer (score 1):

If this is a child form of a parent, you could do something like this:

```
this.Parent.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    Form temp = (Form)this.Parent;
    temp.Opacity = 0.75});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Delegate

```
public class OptionWindow
{
    public delegate void oppacityDelegate(double value);
    public static event oppacityDelegate oppacity;
```

Invoke it

```
private void useOpacity_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (useOpacity.Checked)
     {
       oppacity(.75);
     }
}
```

and catch it in your supperior class

```
OptionWindow.oppacity += ChangeOppacity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `MainWindow` through the constructor of the option window. Then in your option window:

```
public class OptionWindow : Form
{
    Form _mainWindow;                       //YOUR PROGRAM IS OF TYPE Form

    public OptionWindow(Form mainWindow)
    {
        this._mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    private void useOpacity_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (useOpacity.Checked)
         {
           _mainWindow.Opacity = .75;
         }
     }
}
```

And here is when you use the `OptionWindow` from the program

```
OptionWindow window = new OptionWindow(this);
window.Show();
```

Comment: OptionWindow not derived class from System.Windows.Form so can not have Show method. anyway, this code will be circular reference (it will cause stackoverflow exception.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ Thanks. It was forgotten.